# How to parse an XML file with metadata key names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I've recently started using Nokogiri as a solution to parsing data into a RAILS 3 application. The problem I'm having is that I don't fully understand how to do it as the XML I am parsing appears to be 'non-standard'. Take a look at the snippet below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset  xmlns="http://.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!--
<dataset
    xmlns="http://.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://.com/schemas/xmldata/1/ xmldata.xsd"
>
-->
    <metadata>
          <item name="Problem ID" type="xs:string" length="32"/>
          <item name="Account Title" type="xs:string" length="162"/>
          <item name="Account Name" type="xs:string" length="162"/>
          <item name="Reassignment" type="xs:int" precision="1"/>
          <item name="Initial Severity" type="xs:int" precision="1"/>
          <item name="Resolution Desc" type="xs:string" length="510"/>
          <item name="Resolver Name" type="xs:string" length="82"/>
          <item name="Problem Code" type="xs:string" length="32"/>
          <item name="Status" type="xs:string" length="32"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value>AP-06684768    </value>
            <value>ESA</value>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>8</value>
            <value>8</value>
            <value xs:nil="true" />
            <value xs:nil="true" />
            <value>ADDITION TO EXISTING FIREWALL</value>
            <value></value>
            <value>ESA BRIDGE                              </value>
            <value>CLOSED         </value>
            <value>CLOSED         </value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>AP-06720564    </value>
            <value>ESA</value>
            <value>2011-01-19T12:02:47</value>
            <value>2011-01-19T12:02:49</value>
            <value>0</value>
            <value>776</value>
            <value>SCP UESCADADEV -&gt; UESCADAPW/BW</value>
            <value>NETAU_NETMGTS  </value>
            <value>N/A</value>
            <value>ESA BRIDGE                              </value>
            <value>CLOSED         </value>
            <value>CLOSED         </value>
        </row>
    </data>
</dataset>
```

Instead of having named nodes and attributes it seems to be a 'metadata' section and then rows, much like a table really. How would I parse all this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(DATA)
column_names = doc.css('dataset > metadata > item').map {|a| a['name']}

result = doc.css('dataset > data > row').map do |row|
  values = row.css('value').map { |value| value[:nil] == 'true' ? nil : value.content }
  Hash[column_names.zip(values)]
end

pp result
```

results in

```
[{"Problem Code"=>"ADDITION TO EXISTING FIREWALL",
  "Resolution Desc"=>nil,
  "Reassignment"=>"8",
  "Resolver Name"=>nil,
  "Status"=>"",
  "Problem ID"=>"AP-06684768    ",
  "Account Name"=>"1",
  "Initial Severity"=>"8",
  "Account Title"=>"ESA"},
 {"Problem Code"=>"NETAU_NETMGTS  ",
  "Resolution Desc"=>"776",
  "Reassignment"=>"2011-01-19T12:02:49",
  "Resolver Name"=>"SCP UESCADADEV -> UESCADAPW/BW",
  "Status"=>"N/A",
  "Problem ID"=>"AP-06720564    ",
  "Account Name"=>"2011-01-19T12:02:47",
  "Initial Severity"=>"0",
  "Account Title"=>"ESA"}]
```

Comment: Nice, that one is cleaner than mine.

Comment: Oh, and when I was hacking this up late last night, I missed that he was looking for the whole thing and not just the meta data.  Oops.  I'm definitely voting for yours.

Comment: Yep I only really got around to fully testing these tonight and came back to comment. I'll change the answer to John's. Thanks John.

Answer (score 1):

Here's working code that I hacked out and tested:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

class Item
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

file = File.open("data.xml")
document = Nokogiri::XML(file)
file.close

metadata = document.root.children[3]
items = metadata.children.reject{|child| child.attribute('name').nil?}.map do |child|
  Item.new(child.attribute('name').value)
end

puts "#{items.size} items"
puts items.inspect
```

Results:

```
[~/stackoverflow/graphML] ruby parse.rb
9 items
[#<Item:0x007fc01c0fbd90 @id="Problem ID">, #<Item:0x007fc01c0fbca0 @id="Account Title">, #<Item:0x007fc01c0fbc28 @id="Account Name">, #<Item:0x007fc01c0fbbb0 @id="Reassignment">, #<Item:0x007fc01c0fbb38 @id="Initial Severity">, #<Item:0x007fc01c0fbac0 @id="Resolution Desc">, #<Item:0x007fc01c0fba48 @id="Resolver Name">, #<Item:0x007fc01c0fb9d0 @id="Problem Code">, #<Item:0x007fc01c0fb868 @id="Status">]
```

Here's the full project on GitHub: https://github.com/endymion/GraphML-parsing-exercise/tree/metadata-key-names

(It's a branch of a GraphML parsing exercise that I hacked out earlier tonight for somebody else on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Wow impressive work! Thanks. Only thing I don't really understand though is how I then iterate over each row of data?

Comment: At the end of the parsing script, the items in the meta data are in the Ruby array `items`, so you can iterate over them with `items.each {|item| puts item.id}` for example, to get the names and print them.  My example doesn't trap the "length" or "precision" attribute, but you could also add those as attributes to the Item class so that you can access them once the data is parsed into Ruby objects.  Or you could skip the objects and access that information directly from the XML elements with `child.attribute('length').value` from inside of the block in that `map`. The map iterates over items.